# How do you manage common software on a large project?

Tags: project-management

I work on a project far too big to reside in a single Visual Studio / Eclipse / NetBeans project and we have a "common software" team responsible for developing and maintaining software libraries used by other teams.

I'm struggling with how to manage the development of and changes to the common software. When method signatures and classes change, do I keep the old versions and mark them deprecated? The current plan is to distribute a new build of common libraries every two weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely set up a repository. If you are a Maven-hater check out Gradle, it uses Ivy. Maven has a reputation for being complex but it does have better tool support. IDEs support Maven either out-of-the-box or with plugins, they give you graphs showing what the jars in your project depend on, so you can see conflicts easily.

Either Ivy or Maven will sort out your dependencies so your projects are using the right versions. Each of your projects should list (in the pom.xml for Maven) what version of which of your common libraries that it uses.

Comment: We have been using Ivy with a filesystem repository through our build framework for the past 3 months and it has been amazing! The learning curve for our consumers has been very low and they love the ability to transition to Ivy as they wish. Some teams point their projects directly to the Ivy repository on the filesystem and others have created Ivy files and both cases work fantastically.

Answer (score 0):

A common feature of most version control systems is the use of external branches. Common software is fetched from a shared repository and integrated in each project on update. 
A key difficulty lies in documentation changes to the public API of common software and I see two solutions : good communication of deprecated signatures adn continuous integration where finding out deprecated methods can prove painfull.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can have.

**Option A: use a repository**

For Java based systems I would recommend that you use Ant+Ivy or Maven and create an internal repository with the code in those common projects.

**Option B: Classpath Project**
If setting up a repository is too much, what you can do is a create an eclipse project called classpath with the following three directories in it

```
classpath\
  docs\
  sources\
  jars\
```

The team working on the common project can have a build script which complier the common code and places it into the classpath project, all that the rest of the dev team need to do is checkout the classpath project and reference the files in it during development.

Personally I am a fan of option B unless there is a full time person dedicated to doing builds in which case I go for option A.

The way to manage changes in method signatures is to follow a common version convention so when you do a major version number increase you can say dependent code will have to be changed, and if it is a minor version number increase then dependent code does not need to change. marking code as deprecated is a very practical option because IDE and build systems should issue warnings and allow the coders to switch to newer versions. If the same team is changing the common code and the main project then you will need to have the actual eclipse projects all checked out in the same workspace so that re factoring tools can do their job.

Unless the code in common will be used across across many projects I would keep it in all in one project, you can use multiple source folders to make navigating to various parts of the code easy. If you are having trouble with developers checking in stuff that is breaking things, then I would recommend you have more frequent checkins or have developers work on branches where they merge from the trunk to their work branch frequently to eliminate sync problems, when done they can merge from the branch back to the trunk, the latest version of subversion have decent support for this, and DVCS source control systems like mercurial, and git hub are excellent at this.